# How to change Record Type using Salesforce Process Builder without using Record Type ID

Tags: process-builder, record-type

**BACKGROUND**

I would like to change the **record type** of a custom object using **Process Builder**

**QUESTION**

How can I create a process which changes the record type by using the **Developer Name** rather than the **Record Type ID**

Because the ID will change when I deploy the Process

Comment: I think it would be not possible with process builder, but you can achieve that with a flow (query the RecordTypeId by DeveloperName then update the target record)

Comment: a simple invocable apex will do this for you - probably 3 lines of code

Answer (score 3):

I've written an `InvocableMethod` such that you can change a record's record type by using `Developer Name` via Process Builder rather than `RecordTypeID`

[image]

It could be used to change a records record type between *Unlocked* to *Locked* via Process Builder by using the `Developer Name` such that you do not need to update the Process Builder configuration after you deploy from your sandbox into production.

```
public class ChangeRecordTypeAction {

    Private static final String RECORD_TYPE_ID = 'RecordTypeId';

    @InvocableMethod(
        label = 'Change Object Record Type'
        description = 'Change Record Type by Developer Name'
    )
    public static List<Response> execute(List<Request> requests) {

        List<Response> responses = new List<Response>();

        for (Request request : requests) {
            responses.add(updateRecordType(request));
        }

        return responses;
    }

    private static Response updateRecordType(Request request) {

        Response response = new Response();

        try {

            Id recordTypeId = getRecordTypeId(request.objectName, request.developerName);

            if (recordTypeId == null){
                throw new NoRecordTypeFoundException(request);
            }

            String queryString = getQueryString(request.objectName, request.recordId);

            List<sObject> results = Database.query(queryString);

            if (results.size() == 0) {
                throw new NoRecordFoundException(request);
            }

            SObject record = results[0];
            record.put(RECORD_TYPE_ID, recordTypeId);
            update record;

            response.success = true;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            response.errorMesssage = ex.getMessage();
            response.success = false;   
        }

        return response;
    }

    private static String getQueryString(String objectName, String recordId) {
        List<String> args = new String[]{objectName, recordId};
            return String.format('SELECT Id FROM {0} WHERE Id = \'\'{1}\'\'', args);
    }

    private static Id getRecordTypeId(String objectName, String developerName){
        return Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectName).getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName().get(developerName).getRecordTypeId();
    }

    public class Request {

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Record ID'
            description = 'The ID of the record to have its record type changed'
            required = true
        )
        public Id recordId;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Object Name'
            description = 'The Name of the Object which will have its record type changed'
            required = true
        )
        public String objectName;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Record Type Developer Name'
            description = 'The Developer Name of the Record Type to change the object to'
            required = true
        )
        public String developerName;

    }

    public class Response {

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Error Message'
            description = 'The message of the error'
        )
        public String errorMesssage;

        @InvocableVariable(
            label = 'Is Success'
            description = 'Successfully changed'
        )
        public Boolean success;
    }

    private class NoRecordTypeFoundException extends Exception {
        Private Request request;
        public NoRecordTypeFoundException(Request request){
            this.request = request;
        }
        public override String getMessage() {
            List<String> args = new String[]{request.objectName, request.developerName};
            return String.format('No Record Type ID found on object: {0} with Record Type Developer Name: {1}', args);  
        } 
    }

    private class NoRecordFoundException extends Exception {     
        Private Request request;
        public NoRecordFoundException(Request request){
            this.request = request;
        }
        public override String getMessage() {
            List<String> args = new String[]{request.objectName, request.recordId};
            return String.format('No Record found for object: {0} with Record ID: {1}', args); 
        } 
    }
}
```

There is also a unit test:

- [Gist: ChangeRecordTypeAction](https://gist.github.com/ApexUniverse/c465a1a7d15915846d7d86b397532f22)

Comment: this invocable is not bulkified and will blow up if the process builder handles more than 100 records (i.e. in a data loader use case).  You are doing queries and dml within a loop -- should there be triggers on the dml'd objects that in turn do queries, you'll blow up sooner

Comment: @cropredy thanks for the feedback. When you say *bulkified* do you mean I should use `Database.Batchable` or do you mean I need to pre-fetch the data required to perform the process?

Comment: Prefetch.  The invocable needs to be coded in similar style to triggers

Answer (score 1):

Your process will need to include a query that returns the RecordTypeID based on the DeveloperName. This is the same thing one would do if writing a trigger since the RecordTypeId is otherwise not available unless one is using Dynamic Apex which won't be available to you in PB.

Comment: no such thing as a query in process builder...you can store the value in a custom metadata type, and update it manually in prod.  no good option here, other than not to use process builder, which is typically the best option when you have the chance.

Answer (score 1):

When you try and reference the Record Type DeveloperName in Process Builder it shows as  'Record Type Name', as below

[image: process builder screenshot],

As Process Builder only allows you to update the field based on the name so it would need to trigger an autolaunched flow which can look up the record type like the query below and assign its id to a flow variable such as vRecordTypeId with a text type. Then use the record type Id to update the record passed into the flow by the process builder.

[image: this query]

Comment: So we need to use Flow?

Comment: @compski At the time I wrote that answer we needed to use flow. I am going to recheck after current enhancements.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I would only use process builder to launch flows, and do everything in flows.  Soon that step will not be required, but I think that is your best bet given the limitations and lack of improvement on process builder.

In flow, you can query the record type by name using a get records element, and use the ID in a downstream update records element.